# Troubleshoot chef-server-ctl ruby exception

Tags: server, chef-infra, controls

I just upgraded from Chef 11 to the latest 12.x. Install and upgrade went fine, other than having to remove a ref to redis in a config file. However:

```
chef-server-ctrl user-create
```

...barfs with this error:

```
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require': cannot load such file -- chef/knife/ec_base (LoadError)
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/knife-ec-backup-2.0.6/lib/chef/knife/ec_backup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `load'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `block in load_commands'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `each'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:100:in `load_commands'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:110:in `load_command'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:124:in `command_class_from'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife.rb:153:in `subcommand_class_from'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/knife.rb:214:in `run'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:148:in `run'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.12.19/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/knife:23:in `load'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

It seems a file got hosed, somehow. ??? I can't find a way to verify all dependencies were installed during the upgrade, or to do a dependencies-only reinstall. What might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that trying to debug this issue when you have no clue how many older version of Chef are overlapped in the installation is a useless exercise. Nothing in Chef will try to resolve the dependencies, and the installs for upgrades always assume you want to keep all your old, obsolete stuff. The solution was to make a full backup, then delete every trace of anything related to Chef, then install all the components again and follow the instructions to restore the backup.